# How to convert ASCII format into UTF8 in Perl

Tags: perl, utf-8

eg: `&#233;` into `é`

Sometimes user getting ascii format character set rather than french character set... So can any one assist Me is there any function in perl that can convert ascii to UTF-8

Comment: Setting all the most popular tags to your question is not the way to go.

Comment: Maybe you could add some context.. where are the characters shown? A GUI application, in a web browser or in a terminal?

Comment: A GUI application, in a web browser

Answer (score 4):

This is best handled by Perl's built in [`Encode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) module.  Here is a simple example of how to convert a string:

```
my $standard_string = decode("ascii", $ascii_string);
```

(`$standard_string` will then be in whatever Perl's standard encoding is on your system.  In other words, you shouldn't have to worry about it from that point on).

The linked documentation gives many other examples of things you can do--such as setting the encoding of an input file.  A related useful module is [`Encode::Guess`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode/Guess.html), which helps you determine the character encoding if it is unknown.

Comment: @chooban, the question is not really clear about what the input is or where it is coming from.  I didn't know whether `&#233;` was the actual format of the input or the asker's own way of representing a character (the asker of the question didn't put it in code tags; that was an editor's interpretation).  I think this is the best general answer for a "function...that can convert ascii to UTF-8" without knowing more specifics of the problem.

Comment: Good point. I immediately interpreted the question as "How do I make the string '&#233;' become é."

Comment: yes dan1111 and chooban actually my friend raised this qun i dont hve idea on perl so i passed this qun

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to convert HTML entities into UTF-8. To do this, use [HTML::Entities](https://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML::Entities) and the `decode_entities` function.

This will give you a Perl string with no specific encoding attached. To output the string in UTF-8 encoding:

```
print Encode::encode_utf8(decode_entities($html_string));
```

Alternatively, set the UTF-8 PerlIO layer on STDOUT and Perl will encode everything in UTF-8 for you - useful if outputting multiple strings.

```
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
print decode_entities($html_string);
```